# How to avoid views resizing in immersive mode?

Tags: android, insets

I'm using immersive mode when i click on "play" and show system bars again when pressing "stop". I'm using these methods:

```
fun hideSystemUI(container: View) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, container).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }

    fun showSystemUI(container: View) {
        WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)
        WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, container)
            .show(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    }
```

But when i'm going in/out immersive mode my Views are resizing. It looks like my constraints resizing because of parent system bars is no longer on the screen. I tried to use insets:

```
fun View.applyPaddingByInsets(
    applyLeft: Boolean = false,
    applyTop: Boolean = false,
    applyRight: Boolean = false,
    applyBottom: Boolean = false
) {
    ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(this) { view, windowInsets ->
        val insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
        view.updateLayoutParams<ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams> {
            val leftPadding = if (applyLeft) insets.left else 0
            val topPadding = if (applyTop) insets.top else 0
            val rightPadding = if (applyRight) insets.right else 0
            val bottomPadding = if (applyBottom) insets.bottom else 0

            view.updatePadding(leftPadding, topPadding, rightPadding, bottomPadding)
        }
        windowInsets
    }
}
```

I'm applying it on my first top element in Constraint which is parent for the rest views (they connect to bottom of it) and apply it on my last (bottom) view so my middle views connect to the top of it. But the result is the same. Views still resizing. Can you help me to solve this issue? I want my views to stay still in/out of immersive mode

Comment: WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true)

why are you setting this to true when showing the system ui?

Comment: @AagitoEx even if it's false it's still bumping when we turn on/off immersive

Comment: If you are consuming insets then, then a bump is expected. You'll have to look into animated insets for smooth transitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. We need to set `window.attributes.layoutInDisplayCutoutMode` in `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_NEVER` or `LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES`  due to documentation's cutout best practices: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/display-cutout#best_practices_for_display_cutout_support. Also get insets by `windowInsets.getInsetsIgnoringVisibility(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())`